# jFreeChart setLabelFont size not working in GroupedStackedBarRenderer

Tags: jfreechart

I'm using a GroupedStackedBarRenderer to allow a subcategory in my chart. I add the subcategories and control the font size of the subcategory with:

```
    SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("");
    domainAxis.addSubCategory("Skill 1");
    domainAxis.addSubCategory(...)
    domainAxis.setSubLabelFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

But the following line has no effect on the major category itself, the date labels:

```
    plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
    Font font3 = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 16); 
    domainAxis.setLabelFont(font3);
```

On reflection I realize that I need to get a reference to the Category domain axis rather than the subcategory. So I tried the following:

```
   CategoryPlot catPlot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
   catPlot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

But it still didn't work.

Here's my chart:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setTickLabelFont()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setTickLabelFont-java.awt.Font-) to change the font for the tick labels. Use [`deriveFont()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont-float-) to preserve existing font attributes.

```
domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(domainAxis.getTickLabelFont().deriveFont(16f));
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the tick labels were the numbers on the Y axis (Units). I need to change the font size for the X axis dates - "04/11/16"  etc

Comment: I'm assuming that your `domainAxis` is an instance of `SubCategoryAxis`.

Comment: yes it is
`SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("");`

Comment: You are the man - that worked perfectly - I don't know why I didn't see your chart with the dates in big fonts. - blind as usual - thanks again

Comment: @Elliot: Glad you got it sorted; I added the illustration while [editing a typo](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36790704/revisions).